# How to apply certain queries only to those that have an Attribute Exception

Tags: python, django, error-handling

In my Pinterest clone web app, I have cloned their pin's comment section so far like below:

```
try:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.email.split("@")[0], "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
except AttributeError:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.social_id, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
```

This error handling is there because when I tried Q objects like below, it still did not work:

```
pin_comment_info    = [{"user": (Q(comment.user.email.split("@")[0]) | Q(comment.user.socia_id)), "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
```

In the User table, there are users that have email address and that don't. I want the comments to have the author(user)'s email prefix if one exists and social_ids if there is no email in the table. Is there any way to circumvent this AttributeError handing? The very first code only returns user's social_id even when there are some users that have email addresses.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Use an explicit loop.

Comment: Nicholas - somebody up-voted my answer but it had a typo that would stop it working (appending to wrong object). If you are trying it already, please grab a fresh copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an explicit loop.

```
pin_comment_info = []
for comment in pin_comment:
   try:
       user = comment.user.email.split("@")[0]
   except AttributeError:
       user = comment.user.social_id
   pin_comment_info.append({"user": user, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)})
```

Or if you want to use a list comprehension, then first define a function that operates on one comment at a time, and then call that from inside your list comprehension:

```
def get_user(comment):
   try:
       return comment.user.email.split("@")[0]
   except AttributeError:
       return comment.user.social_id

pin_comment_info = [{"user": get_user(comment), "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
```